# Google Maps on website, center is offset?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I want to center my map at these coords [here (google maps website)](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/11+Bank+St/@56.4611388,-2.9719832,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x48865cea830cd645:0x28fb1358868e3d80)

I copy pasted the coordinates in my website code:

```
<script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Because my map slides down from the top of the page when user hovers over some text I call the function to refresh the map at the end of the animation:

```
$('#map').mouseover(function() {
    if ($(this).offset().top == mapHiddenHeight) {
        $(this).animate({
            top: 0
        }, 500, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize'); // refresh map
        }); 
    }
})
```

But the map is slightly offset [from the center on my website](http://rlcoaching.com/albaraka/). (Map drops down when you hover over "Find us on the map", top right)

**NB: Actually I just noticed, if I clear the browser cache and load the website it appears at the right location. It's when you reload the page with cache full that it constantly displays with the same location offset. No matter how many times you refresh the page after that. So it only displays at correct location with a cleared cached, which of course is annoying.**

I don't even know where to start debugging this. Tested on Chrome and Firefox,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there is nothing to "debug", it may sound funny but when there is something that may be called "bug" it's the position you get when it works as expected.

When you trigger the resize-event the API re-calculates the size of the map to be able to load missing tiles. The API will not re-center the map based on the current center/size(the center of a hidden map usually is the location in the northwest-corner).

You must re-center the map on your own.

there are 2 options:

1. **always center the map at the same position:**

   1. store the desired center as a map-option:

      ```
      var map_options = {
       center: new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832),
       zoom: 18,
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
       //default-center, should have same value as center
       originalCenter:new google.maps.LatLng(56.4611388, -2.9719832)
      }
      ```
   2. in the `$.animate`-callback first trigger the resize-event and then set the center of the map:

      ```
      google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
      map.setCenter(map.get('originalCenter'));
      ```
2. **center the map at the center before resizing(when a user drags the map this position will be restored):**
     inside the `$.animate`-callback:

   ```
      var center=map.get('center');
      google.maps.event.trigger(map,'resize');
      map.setCenter(center);
   ```

Comment: Awesome! Solution 1 works perfectly. Any idea though why `originalCenter` doesn't appear here? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

Comment: it's a custom property, you  may set any property you want to.